# Checking username availability in Django using jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, django

I've searched a lot code on the net ... Tried  every single code in the net ... well no one seems to work for my case... what I want is while the input changes, the code will check the availability of that matricule(code). if the matricule is taken, it will display : "Matricule is taken, try another", otherwise, it display nothing.

what should I write in my html tempalte codes, and views.py to get this done

euhh, here's my code :
HTML / Tempalte :

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- <label class="control-label">Code</label> -->
                    <input name="mat_personnel" id="mat_personnel" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Matricule" autofocus="">               
                </div>
```

Here's the view :

```
def checkMatricule(request):

     mat_personnel_form = request.GET.get('mat_personnel', '')

     if Personnels.objects.filter(mat_personnel=mat_personnel_form).count():
         return True

     return False
```

and The url.py :

```
    url(r'^checkMatricule/$', 'Zoe.views.checkMatricule', name='checkMatricule'),
```

and finally the Script inside the templates that gives me a headackes :

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>

 $('#mat_personnel').keyup(function(){  
    var mat_personnel = $("#mat_personnel").val();
    if (mat_personnel == ''){
        return false
    }, "Matricule already exists");
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/checkMatricule/",
        data: {'mat_personnel':mat_personnel},
        success: function(response){
            if (response == "True"){
                return true
            }
            else {
                $("#help_mat_personnel").text("Matricule already exists")
                return false
            }
        }

    })
    });

   $('#check_Form').validate({
    rules: {
        mat_personnel: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 5,
            remote: "/checkMatricule/"
        }
    },
    
});

</script>
```

Thank's

Comment: you need to use jquery ajax to query an api for your site that returns match or available

Comment: its not an answer its a comment ... that should help you search for your answer . first you need to make a page that accepts a username as input and prints if it is in use or not... then you need to use javascirpt (or jquery) to read that page and display the result

Comment: I used all jQuery validator and all views that comes with it ... not working I'm asking if someone did that .. ?, Need Code

Comment: yes ... many registration systems do this ... if you just want someone to do your work for you there are other sites with many freelancer developers who would be happy to do this for you ... from what you have provided someone would have to do your entire work for you ...

Comment: Well, what error are you getting in the console?

Comment: There's no error ?, it just doens't show if the "Matricule" is taken when I put a Matricule already present in the database..... Should it change my Script ?? how ?? ... Thank's